# Disable request validation redirect in Laravel 5.4

Tags: json, laravel, request-validation

So I'm trying to develop a rest API for an internal project, and I've got an issue where when the form request validation fails, it shows the @index response.

So I have two routes;

```
Route::get('/api/clients', 'ClientController@index');
Route::post('/api/clients', 'ClientController@store');
```

`@index` lists all clients, `@store` creates a new client and I've got a Form Request Validator on the `@store` method which checks a name is provided for the client.

What I want is when the validator fails, it shows a JSON response with the validation errors. But what I think it happening, is the validation fails, so it redirects back to the same page, but the redirect is `GET` instead of `POST`, so it lists all the clients instead.

I know that you can set your headers so that it looks like an ajax request, in which it will show the JSON response properly, but I want it to show the JSON response regardless of whether it's ajax or not.

I've tried overriding the `response` method in my validator which didn't work, I've tried setting the `wantsJson` method in the validator to return true which again didn't work.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Code is below...

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/api/clients', 'ClientController@index');
Route::get('/api/clients/{client}', 'ClientController@show');
Route::post('/api/clients', 'ClientController@store');
Route::put('/api/clients/{id}', 'ClientController@update');
Route::delete('/api/clients/{id}', 'ClientController@delete');
```

**ClientController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Client;
use App\Http\Requests\ClientRequest;

class ClientController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(ClientRequest $request)
    {
        return Client::create([
            'title'   => request('title'),
            'user_id' => auth()->id()
        ]);
    }
```

**ClientRequest.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ClientRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the failed validation response for the request.
     *
     * @param array $errors
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
     public function response(array $errors)
     {
         dd('exit'); // Doesn't work
     }
}
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can try like this

Include use first as below in your form request

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
```

and then

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));
    }
```

now if you try to validate then it will return like

```
{
"title": [
"The  title field is required."
]
}
```

Comment: exactly what im looking for!

Comment: It's so refreshing to see a well thought out Laravel question online and an answer to match!

Comment: Throwing an error is a great idea. Thank you :)

Answer (score 78):

When making the request we should send header info.

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

That's it, now laravel will not redirect and send the error message as JSON.

Comment: yeah, this is what I'm facing right now when using postman. There is no error message when validate failed. it just redirects to the index page. thanks, man...

Comment: You can set in your collection's pre-request scripts to automatically set the `Accept` header:
`pm.request.headers.upsert({ key: 'Accept', value: 'application/json' })`

Answer (score 21):

Try this

Open app/Exceptions/Handler.php file

Include use

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
```

and then add method

```
    /**
     * Create a response object from the given validation exception.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException  $e
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function convertValidationExceptionToResponse(ValidationException $e, $request)
    {
        if ($e->response) {
            return $e->response;
        }

        return response()->json($e->validator->errors()->getMessages(), 422);
    }
```

now you can get standard validationFailure response like ajax request

Answer (score 8):

There is **two ways** to work with validator errors, *my suggestion is second way*:

**1.** First way, Simply return an error when validation fail's(in controller).
Example:

```
    try {
        request()->validate([
            'input1' => 'required',
            'input2' => 'string|min:5',
        ]);

    } catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e){
        return response('The given data was invalid.', 400);

    }
```

Handy and clean.

**2.** Second way is show full errors to user(in controller), like this:

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

    $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
         'id' => 'required|integer',
         'description' => 'string'
    ]);

    // return array of errors to client with status code 400
    if ($validator->fails())
        return response($validator->messages()->toArray(), 400);
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply use this trait to prevent redirect after `FormRequest` validation.
The following trait is also brings some useful public methods, such as:

- `validatorPasses()`
- `validatorFails()`
- `validatorErrors()`
- `respondWithErrorsJson(int $code = 422)`
- `redirectWithErrors()` - restores the default Laravel FomrRequest behavior

### Trait

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

trait PreventsRedirectWhenFailedTrait
{
    /**
     * Default self::failedValidation() Laravel behavior flag.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    private $defaultFailedValidationRestored = false;

    /**
     * Check for validator success flag.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validatorPasses(): bool
    {
        return !$this->validatorFails();
    }

    /**
     * Check for validator fail flag.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validatorFails(): bool
    {
        return $this->getValidatorInstance()->fails();
    }

    /**
     * @return MessageBag
     */
    public function validatorErrors(): MessageBag
    {
        return $this->getValidatorInstance()->errors();
    }

    /**
     * Respond with validator errors in JSON format.
     *
     * @param  int  $code
     */
    public function respondWithErrorsJson(int $code = 422): void
    {
        if ($this->validatorFails()) {
            throw new HttpResponseException(
                response()->json(['errors' => $this->getValidatorInstance()->errors()], $code)
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Restore and apply default self::failedValidation() method behavior.
     *
     * @throws ValidationException
     */
    public function redirectWithErrors(): void
    {
        $this->defaultFailedValidationRestored = true;

        $this->failedValidation($this->getValidatorInstance());
    }

    /**
     * Handle a failed validation attempt.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator  $validator
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator): void
    {
        if ($this->defaultFailedValidationRestored) {
            throw (new ValidationException($validator))
                ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
                ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage example:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AuthRequest extends FormRequest
{
    use PreventsRedirectWhenFailedTrait;

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return Auth::guest();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email|exists:users',
            'password' => 'required',
            'remember_me' => 'integer',
        ];
    }
}
```

### Inside your controller:

```
public function authenticate(AuthRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->validatorPasses()) {
            $data = $request->validated();
            /* your logic */
        } else {
            $errorBag = $request->validatorErrors();
        }

        // or
        if ($request->validatorFails()) {
            // your logic
        }
}
```

Hope you'll find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm in laravel 8 as well

Answer (score 4):

I made a middleware (for API requests only) to make the Accept header include application/json by default:

```php
/**
 * Ensures the default Accept header is application/json
 */
class DefaultApiAcceptJson
{
    public function handle(Request $request, \Closure $next)
    {
        $acceptHeader = $request->headers->get('Accept');
        if (!Str::contains($acceptHeader, 'application/json')) {
            $newAcceptHeader = 'application/json';
            if ($acceptHeader) {
                $newAcceptHeader .= "/$acceptHeader";
            }
            $request->headers->set('Accept', $newAcceptHeader);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This way I always get the validation error JSON response rather than a redirect to the web index page.

Answer (score 3):

I just created a `ApiFormRequest` who override [`FormRequest::failedValidation`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html#method_failedValidation) method like this:

```
<?php
// app/Http/Requests/ApiFormRequest.php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

class ApiFormRequest extends FormRequest
{

    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator): void
    {
        $jsonResponse = response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);

        throw new HttpResponseException($jsonResponse);
    }
}
```

Then you simply use like this

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ClientRequest extends ApiFormRequest
{
    // ...
```