# Getting Not Found error whenever the validation fails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am getting **Not Found** error whenever the validation fails whereas I should be getting the validation error. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? The code below executes perfectly when all the inputs are available.

this is my routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::post('/change-password', 'API\AuthController@changePassword');
}
```

this is my controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class AuthController extends Controller {

    public function changePassword(Request $request) {
        $rules = [
            'old_password' => 'required',
            'new_password' => 'required|min:6',
            'confirm_password' => 'required|same:new_password',
        ];

        $customMessages = [
            'required' => 'The :attribute field can not be blank.'
        ];

        $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);

        if (! \Hash::check($request->old_password, $request->user()->password)) {
            return response()->json([
                "message" => "Please check your old password"
            ], 400 , [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
        }
        else if (\Hash::check($request->new_password, $request->user()->password)) {
            return response()->json([
                "message" => "New password is same as the old password"
            ], 400 , [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
        }
        else {
            User::where('id', $request->user()->id)->update([
                'password' => \Hash::make($request->new_password)
            ]);
            return response()->json([
                "message" => "Password updated successfully"
            ], 200 , [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it redirecting you to the previous page if the validation fails?

Comment: Not found, do you mean 404 not found?

Comment: @STA Yes, it sends a 404 response.

Comment: @Tushar I am building an api.

Comment: @RavgeetDhillon, I guess as the default behavior of laravel is to redirect to the previous page when vaildation fails, that's why you are getting 404 when your vaildation fails. I think you probably need to somehow prevent it redirecting and send you the response back in json. Maybe you can try setting these when make a request:

Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json


For more info please refer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350307/disable-request-validation-redirect-in-laravel-5-4

Comment: Hurray. Thanks @Tushar. You are right, since I am developing an API, I need to add Accept header.

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you!

Comment: Can you please also add the ajax request ?

Comment: xhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");